# n-th self discrete convolution

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, convolution

Lets define discrete $ f_N(i) = 1,\space i = 1...N $

I need to find $ G_N^m = \underbrace {f_N * f_N * ... * f_N}_{m} $

For example $G_6^3$ have value (1,3,6,10,15,21,25,27,27,25,21,15,10,6,3,1) , which is palyndromic and have $\binom{i}{2} $ as first 5 values.

So it seems to be common rule, every $G_N^m$ is palyndromic, have $mN - m + 1$ values total and have $\binom {i} {m-1}$ as first $ N-1$ values.

But i wonder if there general formula for $G_N^m(i)$ ?

Additional information about [discrete convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution):
values of $G_N^m$ are coefficients of $(\frac{x^N - 1}{x -1})^m$ polynomial

Comment: Privet! What $*$ operations means? I guess it regular multiplication, \cdot - $\cdot$?

Comment: @SalechAlhasov No it's discrete convolution http://goo.gl/I8bJ2

Comment: Interesting! Thanks!

Comment: These numbers are [OEIS A109439](http://oeis.org/A109439); the entry gives no formula for them other than the generating function, which you already know, so I suspect that no nicer formula is known.

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456408/repeated-discrete-convolution ?